# MySQL Query Not show duplicate id

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop-1.6

I want to make not showing if duplicate id_customer on my query is ,

```
SELECT
    ps_orders.id_customer,
    ps_customer.firstname,
    ps_customer.lastname,
    ps_customer.email,
    ps_orders.total_paid
FROM
    ps_orders
    RIGHT JOIN ps_customer 
        on ps_orders.id_customer = ps_customer.id_customer
WHERE
    ps_orders.total_paid > 1
GROUP BY
    ps_orders.id_customer;
```

I'm doing by using "group by" but it doesn't show. I want it wont show anything even that group by

Showing like this

```
 id_customer    firstname   lastname    email   total_paid
--------------------------------------------------------
55  name8   name10  ***@windowslive.com 88.90
58  name6   name7   ****@hotmail.com    78.90
59  name3   name5   ****@hotmail.com    123.83
60  name    name2   ****@hotmail.com    78.90
```

First query was like this ,

```
SELECT
    ps_orders.id_customer,
    ps_customer.firstname,
    ps_customer.lastname,
    ps_customer.email,
    ps_orders.total_paid
FROM
    ps_orders
    RIGHT JOIN ps_customer 
        on ps_orders.id_customer = ps_customer.id_customer
WHERE
    ps_orders.total_paid > 1
ORDER BY
    ps_orders.id_customer;
```

Without group by

```
 id_customer    firstname   lastname    email   total_paid
--------------------------------------------------------
55  name8   name10  ***@windowslive.com 88.90
58  name6   name7   ****@hotmail.com    56.00
58  name6   name7   ****@hotmail.com    87.90
58  name6   name7   ****@hotmail.com    79.99
58  name6   name7   ****@hotmail.com    78.90
59  name3   name5   ****@hotmail.com    123.83
60  name    name2   ****@hotmail.com    78.90
```

But i want to see like this

```
 id_customer    firstname   lastname    email   total_paid
--------------------------------------------------------
55  name8   name10  ***@windowslive.com 88.90
59  name3   name5   ****@hotmail.com    123.83
60  name    name2   ****@hotmail.com    78.90
```

Comment: could you post what result do you have now, and what is expected result?

Comment: @Alex please check it again.

Comment: so which one is EXPECTED result?

Comment: @alex i add what i want to see :)

Comment: why `id_customer=58` should be removed from the resultset? what is your criteria?

Comment: @Alex Because who is customer 58 make 5 orders. I'm trying to select who make just one order from mysql. That is my criteria for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    ps_orders.id_customer,
    ps_customer.firstname,
    ps_customer.lastname,
    ps_customer.email,
    ps_orders.total_paid
FROM
    ps_orders
    JOIN ps_customer 
        on ps_orders.id_customer = ps_customer.id_customer
WHERE
    ps_orders.total_paid > 1
    AND ps_orders.id_customer IN (  SELECT  ps_orders.id_customer
                                    FROM    ps_orders
                                    GROUP BY ps_orders.id_customer
                                    HAVING COUNT(1) < 2 )
```

Comment: I think this is what OP meant (I had a different interpretation). I would go with your answer now. Just note that the `right join` acts as `inner` becaue of the `total_paid` condition.

Comment: @trincot - Corrected my query. I didnt pay much attention at the selected variables, was just focused on eliminating the customer_id with count higher than 1 :)

Comment: I will remove my answer, yours is better :)

Comment: Thanks alot that is fix my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check `HAVING`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a981f/1

```
SELECT
    ps_orders.id_customer,
    ps_customer.firstname,
    ps_customer.lastname,
    ps_customer.email,
    ps_orders.total_paid
FROM
    ps_orders
    RIGHT JOIN ps_customer 
        on ps_orders.id_customer = ps_customer.id_customer
GROUP BY
    ps_orders.id_customer
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

Comment: Won't you get _'it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause'_ error??